# __str__ and single vs double quote behavior in Python

Tags: python, quotes

If I define a dict with a string as in

```
d = {"5": 5}
```

print displays with single quotes

```
>> print d
>> {'5': 5}
```

Is there a way to make it print with double quotes?

EDIT:

The full story is I originally defined a tree as nested dictionaries and transferred it between languages using json.  I then decided to wrap the dictionaries in a class, but that broke my method for encoding it in json.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: Doing this correctly, covering all corner cases, would be hard.  If you are actually trying to write JSON output, use the `json` module.

Answer (score 9):

Yes (assuming you have the `json` module):

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({'5': 5})
{"5": 5}
>>>
```

---

On number of quotes when using `print`, the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) say:

> The string is enclosed in double quotes if the string contains a
>   single quote and no double quotes, else it’s enclosed in single
>   quotes.

Comment: Note that this won't work if your dict contains types that aren't JSON-serializable (such as `bytes`).

Comment: Worse: It will assume all dictionary keys are strings; `print json.dumps({5:5})` gives `{"5": 5}`. This is dictated by the JSON standard.

Comment: @hochl the primary reason for **wanting** double-quotes here, beyond a more or less irrelevant aesthetic preference, is that you actually are trying to output JSON.

Comment: @matt Ironically I want to turn a dict that I can only print out into a json object by printing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: create your own function which traverses the dict, building your own string representation, then print that.

Alternatively, encode it as JSON or YAML, which will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> d = {"5": 5}
>>> for key,value in d.items():
    print('{{"{0}": {1}}}'.format(key,value))


{"5": 5}
```

Just use double `{` if you want to output `{` with [`format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) method.

---

Here is the solution with using of `__str__` method:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import chain,izip,repeat

class singleQuoteDict(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(chain(('{'),
                      (j for i in izip(
                          chain([''],repeat(', ')),
                          ('"{0}": {1!r}'.format(key,value) for key,value in self.items()))
                       for j in i),
                      ('}')))


d = singleQuoteDict({"5": 5, "10": 10})
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{"10": 10, "5": 5}
```

Comment: Might be better to use `'{{"{0}": {1!r}}}'` to ensure that the values are from `repr()` and not `str()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a subclass of the dictionary type and define your own string representation:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "my representation"
```

For example:

```
>>> d = MyDict()
>>> d["5"] = 5
>>> d
my representation
```